# Capture "clicking of reply/reply all" events in Outlook VSTO C#

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, visual-studio-2019

currently I am working with creating add-in's for VSTO Outlook using C# language.

I learnt some basics from [Microsoft's Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2019), where **I learnt to add some text to mail body whenever user composes a new mail.**

**I want to do the same(adding text to mail body) for both reply and reply all events.**

I searched through the Outlook Object model, but found nothing useful.
Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Explorer.SelectionChange` event to set up event sinks on the selected items (`Explorer` object can come from the `Application.ActiveExplorer` property), then track the `MailItem.Reply` / `ReplyAll` events.

If you don't care about the old item, you can simply use `Inspectors.NewInspector` event.

Comment: For me the `SelectionChange` does not fire when the user starts a reply from the context menu on an unopened `MailItem`. Is it possible to catch that event as well?

Comment: In that case, `Inspectors.NewInspector` event will fire. In the reply is created inline, `Explorer.InlineResponse` will fire.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but in these cases the `MailItem` will be the "quoted" one, right? I want to modify the "original" `MailItem` before it gets quoted. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, in case of a popup menu, there is no way to figure out the original message. You can if the user clicks on *your* popup menu item, but not in case of a built-in one.